# ASP.Net Session is lost

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

We have the following web server and ASP.Net application specs:

- Windows 2012 R2
- IIS 8.5
- ASP.Net Application using .Net 4.0
- Classic managed pipeline
- InProc session "UseCookies"

We have a problem when a successful login redirect to inner page which check the session keys to proceed, at that certain point the session keys are clear, where as I checked chrome developer tools I found that the asp.net cookie has no value.

I referred to other threads with the same problem but nothing helped, where all solutions been provided was to play with code where actually the same code and  setup above is running fine on other servers, so my suspect is may be windows, .Net or IIS settings, where I have tested it locally on the same server using "http://localhost" and I disabled any tools like (firewall, antivirus, etc...) but it was useless.

Is there any configuration I should check?

Comment: If the cookies is being lost...maybe it just timed-out... Try increasing the session and forms authentication cookies time

Comment: I increased the session timeout, but how to increase forms authentication cookies time?

Comment: If you are using forms authentication - then you can increase the timeout in web.config: <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Home/LoginNew.aspx" timeout="4000" ...

Comment: I tried the form config item too but it is useless, I am afraid a certain windows update has changed some settings in IIS or .Net